# I want to make a repeat statement that repeats the while statement under the for statement

Tags: python

It's a repeating sentence structure, but I don't know what to do.

```
keys = [1,2,3,4]
num = 1
maxNum = 3

for key in keys :
    print('key',key)
    while num < maxNum + 1 : 
        print('num',num)

        num = num + 1
    continue
```

It's like this.
What I want to do is when the conditions are over,
I want to go to the for door and change the value of the key.
Even if I put "continue" on the while or if door, it doesn't go over and ends.
Is there any way?

```
key 1
num 1
num 2
num 3
key 2
num 1
num 2
num 3
key 3
num 1
num 2
num 3
key 4
num 1
num 2`enter code here`
num 3
```

I want this.

Comment: What is "the for door"?

Comment: So you want `num` to be 1 each time the `while` loop starts?  What is preventing you from making this happen?

Comment: Hint: what should be the value of `num`, at the time that the `while` loop starts? Should it start with that value every time? Can you think of a way to make that happen? What if you tried assigning a value to `num`?

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note, if you simply intend to have a fixed number of cycles for each key, a `for` loop seems more explicit and appropriate:

```
keys = [1,2,3,4]
num = 1
maxNum = 3

for key in keys :
    print('key', key)
    for n in range(num, num+maxNum): 
        print('num', n)
```

Output:

```
key 1
num 1
num 2
num 3
key 2
num 1
num 2
num 3
key 3
num 1
num 2
num 3
key 4
num 1
num 2
num 3
```

Another approach for looping a n*m set, is to loop on `range(n*m)` and use `divmod` to keep track of each index:

```
for i in range(len(keys)*maxNum):
    d,r = divmod(i, maxNum)
    if not r: # or if r == 0
        print('key', keys[d])
    print('num', r+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

change code to this :

```
keys = [1,2,3,4]
num = 1
maxNum = 3

for key in keys :
    print('key',key)
    while num < maxNum + 1 : 
        print('num',num)
        num = num + 1
    num = 1
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the value of num outside the inner while loop.
Something like this:

```
keys = [1,2,3,4]
num = 1
maxNum = 3

for key in keys :
    print('key',key)
    num = 1
    while num < maxNum + 1 : 
        print('num',num)
        num = num + 1
    continue
```

Comment: This answer is basically the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70554011/14193797) one. Why do you feel the need to repost it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to debug your code and understand the flow for better learning . There is just a small change required here , since you need to repeat the value of `num` for each `key` so it should be inside the loop block .

```
keys = [1,2,3,4]
#num = 1 (not required here)
maxNum = 3

for key in keys :
    print('key',key)
    num = 1
    while num < maxNum + 1 : 
        print('num',num)

        num = num + 1
    continue
```

Comment: This answer is basically the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70554011/14193797) one. Why do you feel the need to repost it?

Comment: @justANewbie not sure if this was worth a semi-duplicate, but this one doesn't needlessly duplicate the `num = 1` assignment.

Comment: @mozway IMO this is basically the same solution. For example, if I post another answer using f-string instead, that doesn't count as a another solution